# How to Use the "collapsing" Bootstrap 4 Class Selector With Sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to collapse a sidebar and add a transition affect. From reading the Bootstrap documentation, this can be done using the "collapsing" selector. However, I do not know how or where to apply it.

I've tried adding the "collapsing" select to the class attribute for the side bar and also tried custom styles to it in a css file, but that didn't worked.

The collapse works fine, I just cannot get a transition to work against it.

Here's my basic html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3 collapse show">
                <p>Sidebar Content</p>
            </div>

            <div id="content" class="col">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebar" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you want the sidebar menu to dropdown from there???

Comment: No. Later, when I do add a menu, I want the dropdowns to show to the right. But I have that handled. For now, I just want to collapse the whole sidebar and when doing so, use a transition to smooth out the show and collapse of the sidebar

Answer (score 0):

is this smth you want:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent"
      aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="pos-f-b">
    <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
      <div class="bg-dark p-4">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No, but thanks for the response. Not only is this not using a sidebar affect, it doesn't do a transition. I can already hide/unhide a sidebar (as my demo shows). I'm trying to smooth out the hide/unhide of a sidebar with a transition and the collapsing seletor

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with jsfiddle and collapse works already with transition, so there is nothing wrong with that?

(I only added more content to the sidebar and a red border.)

[image]

1. Maybe your browser have set the `prefers-reduced-motion` [feature](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/accessibility/#reduced-motion)? Then transition won't apply.
2. Maybe your expectation of the transition is not correct, so you want the nav-bar to transition from right to left?